# How to constrain the return type of a function with an arbitrary amount of arguments?

Tags: f#

I would like to create a record type with a type annotation, with the constraint that the annotation must be a function that returns a certain type. Consider this example below:

```ml
type Foo<'Function> = {
    Function: 'Function
}
```

I would `'Function` to be able to be any function, as long as it returns for example `int`, so that

```
{Function = (fun a b c d e f g -> 2)}
{Function = (fun a -> 2)}
```

work, but

```
{Function = (fun a -> "")}
```

would be invalid.

As far as i understand F# functions, they are a nested structure of tuples, where the most inner second tuple field is the return type of the function, which is the reason why neither of these:

```ml
type Foo<('Input -> int)> = {
    Function: ('Input -> int)
}

type ReturnsInt = FSharpFunc<'Input,int>
```

will work for any function with more than one argument, because the result type is encapsulated in the second annotation in either the signature or `FSharpFunc<_,_>`. Is there a way to realize this as a type annotation?

### Edit

As Fyodor suggested in the comments below, this can be overcome by using only functions that have tupled arguments, leading to the function annotation being

`FSharpFunc<argumentTuples,ReturnType>`, e.g.:

```ml
type Foo<'ArgumentTuples> = {
    Function: 'ArgumentTuples -> int
}

{Function = (fun (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) -> 2)} // works
{Function = (fun a -> 2)} // works
{Function = (fun a -> "")} // wont work
```

While this approach has its own problems and is not the specific answer to the original question, this workaround/workflow adaptation might be enough for me. I'll leave this question up (can't mark the comment as answer anyways)

Comment: Why do you need this? I mean, how do you plan to use such type after you achieve this goal?

Comment: Without going too deep into details, lots of reflection downstream. I zip the function's (arbitrary amount of) input types with JTokens from a JSON source, convert the tokens to to the input types and then invoke the function with the correctly typed arguments. To make this more safe i would like to constrain all of this to be only usable for functions that return a specific type that must be constructed in a specific way.

Comment: With that ultimate goal in mind, I would recommend making the parameters tupled rather than curried. That way your reflection code can recognize the tuple type and initialize it with correctly typed parameters.

Comment: That might be the best approach here so far, thanks. It adds the complexety of flattening the input tuples though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but why not simply define your type as:

```
type Foo<'InputType> = {
    Function: ('InputType -> int)
}
```

Or more generic:

```
type Foo<'InputType, 'OutputType> = {
    Function: ('InputType -> 'OutputType)
}
```

Edit: Ok, I see the problem.
So to use Fyodors solution, do something like this:

```
type Foo<'InputType> = {
    Function: ('InputType -> int)
}

let add a b = a + b

let myFunction = {
    Function = (fun (a,b) -> add a b)
}
```

Comment: That will only work for functions with one input argument, as i tried to show in the last codeblock in the question.

Comment: Duh! Ok, then I suggest Fyodors solution if applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines might work for you, although you should be careful about not loosing the general picture. The branching may explode if there is a lot of complexity in your data model.

```
module FunctionTests

//define function types templates
type F1<'a> = 'a -> int
type F2<'a, 'b> = 'a -> 'b -> int
type F3<'a, 'b, 'c> = 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> int
type F4<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd> = 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> int

//define actual functions
let f1 : F1<string> = fun x -> 
                        printf "calling f1: %s\n" x
                        1
let f2 : F2<string, string> = fun x y -> 
                        printf "calling f2: %s; %s\n" x y
                        2
let f3 : F3<string, string, int> = fun x y z -> 
                        printf "calling f2: %s; %s; %d\n" x y z
                        3
let f4 : F4<string, string, int, int> = fun x y z v -> 
                        printf "calling f2: %s; %s; %d; %d\n" x y z v
                        4

//define DU limiting to a subset of functions
type FunctionChooser = 
    | FF1 of F1<string>
    | FF2 of F2<string, string>
    | FF3 of F3<string, string, int>
    | FF4 of F4<string, string, int, int>

//define a record with the DU
type FunctionRec = {Function : FunctionChooser}


//testing harness
let callFunction (functiondefs : FunctionRec) data otherdata intparam1 intparam2 = 
    match functiondefs.Function with
    | FF1 fn -> fn data
    | FF2 fn -> fn data otherdata
    | FF3 fn -> fn data otherdata intparam1
    | FF4 fn -> fn data otherdata intparam1 intparam2


//tests
let res1 = callFunction {Function=FF1 f1} "somedata" "otherdata" 13 14
let res2 = callFunction {Function=FF2 f2} "somedata" "otherdata" 13 14
let res3 = callFunction {Function=FF3 f3} "somedata" "otherdata" 13 14
let res4 = callFunction {Function=FF4 f4} "somedata" "otherdata" 13 14
```